# Design custom PCB for esp32

Tags: pcb, esp32

This video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndEeFQ5mi_g ) explains how to program an esp32 chip. I will like to design my custom PCB without using the one from the video.

So my question is where can I find the diagram of this PCB:
https://www.sunrom.com/p/breakout-pcb-for-esp32-esp-32s

I already managed to flash my code to the esp32 chip using [this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083Q8GR99).

[image]

Now that my code is running on the esp32 chip if I where to power it giving 3.3V will it work? what happens if I do not solder the pins that I am not using? For example if I only solder the 3.3V pin with 3.3V, the ground pin and pin 2 to turn on and off and LED will it work?

Comment: You question is extremely broad in scope and cannot really be answered.  Let me suggest that you start with the ESP32 datasheet and also study one of the many ESP32 modules out there that have schematics available.  Once you understand this device better then you will probably be able to make some intelligent design decisions for your project.

Comment: Or I will just buy that breakout board and reverse engineer it.

Comment: That's also an option.

Comment: A lot of breakout boards should have easily found schematics on the internet (that's what they are/should be for, developing/prototyping). So no reverse engineering necessary.

Comment: I been trying to find one that is simple. I already have a 3.3V battery. I do not need a voltage regulator for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run the LED blink sketch like this:

[image]

I had to program the chip with the help of the part posted on the question.